# How can I tell which keys, if any, in a ruby hash same the same value?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a Ruby hash that may have keys with the same value -- for example, the same array.

How would I write a method (duplicate_values) that determines which keys, if any, have the same value?

The duplicate_values method should return an array of the keys that have the same value.

Examples:

```
h = {}

h[:a] = [1, 2, 3]

h[:b] = [1, 2, 4]

h.duplicate_values # returns []

h = {}

h[:a] = [1, 2, 3]

h[:b] = [4, 5, 6]

h[:c] = [1, 2, 3]

h.duplicate_values # returns [:a, :c]
```

Comment: Are these going to be identical *objects* or just coincidentally identical *contents*?

Answer (score 4):

The most logical approach is to use [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
# Group the keys by...
h.keys.group_by do |k|
  # ...the value they contain in the hash.
  h[k]
# Out of those select the entries...
end.select do |k, v|
  # ...that have duplicates.
  v.length > 1
# Then find out what keys those are from the grouped list(s)
end.flat_map(&:last)
```

Since Ruby doesn't really care if you're comparing an array to an array, a string to a string, or a symbol to a symbol, you can use `group_by` straight-up without any fuss. This will also work on other types of data just the same.

The key here is to strip out non-duplicates, and then to extract the resulting keys from the grouped arrays.

If you want to know the matching groups, you can switch `flat_map`, which combines them all into one array, to `map`, which keeps them separated. That would return results like `[[:a,:b],[:f:,g:]]` if you had two different groups of duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6], c:[1, 2, 3], d: [7, 8, 9], e: [4, 5, 6] }
```

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }.
  select { |_,v| v.size > 1 }.
  flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [:a, :c, :b, :e]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
f = h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v] ||= []) << k }
  #=> {[1, 2, 3]=>[:a, :c], [4, 5, 6]=>[:b, :e], [7, 8, 9]=>[:d]}
g = f.select { |_,v| v.size > 1 }
  #=> {[1, 2, 3]=>[:a, :c], [4, 5, 6]=>[:b, :e]}
g.flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [:a, :c, :b, :e]
```

```
h[v] ||= []
```

is expanded to:

```
h[v] = h[v] || []
```

so when `h` has no key `v`, the expression reduces to:

```
h[v] = nil || []
  #=> []
```

As the value of `v` is returned, `(h[v] ||= []) << k` appends `k` to the empty array. If `h` has a key `k`, the expression reduces to `h[v] << k`.